# Parameterized testing with Nightwatch (Data Driven Testing)

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, data-driven-tests

I need to parameterize my automated tests so they can run with multiple sets of data (i.e. data driven testing). I'm using Nightwatch and the most close to a result for it i found [this Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nightwatchjs/L3mNDrAzeN4) which practically says it's not supported. And i don't have the skills to try to modify the Nightwatch core code in order to support this.

I've been using in TestNG like this:

```
package parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
// [...] 
@Test
@Parameters({"param1","param2"})
public void testParameter(String param1, String param2)
// [..]
```

for reading from the testng.xml which contains the test configuration:

```
<suite name="Smoke Test" thread-count="1">
  <parameter name = "productName" value = "Bonbons" />
  <parameter name = "productID" value = "09464703" />
  <test name = "ProductInfo">
    <classes>
      <class name = "parameters.testParameter">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Is there any custom javascript library that would help with this in Nightwatch? or maybe there is a way to integrate it with some other tool? (By my knowledge, Nightwatch is built on top on Node.Js which doesn't have a support for data driven testing either, but it integrates with other tools in order to achieve this.)

Answer (score 1):

One way I have solved the problem of needing tests to run with many combinations of data is to use a template for everything that is the same in all tests and use node to create all of the test files with that template and each combination of data variables.

I needed all the tests ready to use nightwatches worker processes to run ~20 browsers at the same time. I had 4 environments, each with 4 sites, each with 4 login types, each with 4 payment types, each with 4 card types for 1024 tests to test each combination.

I'm not saying this is the easiest solution. It's just how I did it to allow worker processes to work with many environments and maybe a tweaked version could be helpful for you:

```
var config = require("../globals").config;
var _ = require('underscore');
var fs = require('fs');

var template = fs.readFileSync('testTemplate.js');

_.each(config.environments, function (env) {
    _.each(config.sites, function (site) {
        _.each(config.logins, function (login) {
            _.each(config.paymentTypes, function (paymentType) {
                _.each(config.cardTypes, function (cardType) {

    var testName = env.name+'-'+site.name+'-'+login.name+'-'+paymentType.name+'-'+cardType.name;

    var s = "var _ = require('underscore');\n\n";
    s += "var env = '" + env.name + "';\n";
    s += "var site = '" + site.name + "';\n";
    s += "var login = '" + login.name + "';\n";
    s += "var paymentType = '" + paymentType.name + "';\n";
    s += "var cardType = '" + cardType.name + "';\n\n";
    s += "module.exports = {\n";
    s += "\t'@tags': ['"+env.name+"','"+site.name+"','"+login.name+"','"+adultType.name+"','"+paymentType.name+"','"+cardType.name+"'],\n";
    s += "\t'"+testName+"' : function (browser) {\n";
    s += template;

    fs.writeFile('./tests/'+env.name+'-'+login.name+'/'+testName+'.js', s, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('s > '+env.name+'/'+testName+'.js');
    });

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It was also helpful to set up a script file to automatically create all tests I needed then run nightwatch for the tests I wanted.

So basically you pull in the data you need in node, convert it to a format your tests will easily understand (...JS, JSON), create all necessary tests, and run them either by setting tags or running a test folders with all the created tests in them.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by providing auxiliary class that you can use in this way:

1. Install ***nightwatch-data-driven*** module:

   npm i nightwatch-data-driven
2. Import ***DataDrivenTest*** class in your test module:

   `import DataDrivenTest from 'nightwatch-data-driven'`
3. Use the class like this:

   ```
   // . Initialize DataDrivenTest with browser and AAA function
   //   and call it for a set of test cases
   new DataDrivenTest(browser, function(data, name){
       // . Arrange
       browser.logout();
       // . Act
       browser.page.login().loginAndWaitForRedirect(data.email, data.pass);
       // . Assert
       browser.page.workspace().assertIsCurrentPage(name);
   })
   .forCases({
       "Valid credentials": {email: authConfig.main.EMAIL, pass: authConfig.main.PASS},
       "Ignore leading space in email": {email: ' ' + authConfig.main.EMAIL, pass: authConfig.main.PASS},
       "Email in upper case": {
           email: authConfig.main.EMAIL.toUpperCase(),
           pass: authConfig.main.PASS,
           disabled: true
       }
   });
   ```

[Link to Github repository](https://github.com/wsbaser/nightwatch-data-driven)

Comment: nice! looks like it's a good solution, will try to adapt it to my tests! thanks!